# Check if the selected element contains white space

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to check if the element is empty.

My element could be something like

```
<table>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>text</td>
</table>
```

I have tried:

```
$('table td').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':empty')){
    console.log('found;)
  }
})
```

and

```
$('table td').each(function(){
  if($(this).html()=='&nbsp;'){
    console.log('found')
  }
})
```

but I can't seem to find it. Anyway I can accomplish this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to check if it's empty or if it has white space?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `$.trim` like below,

```
$.trim($(this).text()) === ''
```